# AS3 - unbalanced stack?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a board for a game, using a movie clip Block in my library. My code is in a linked actionscript file, and looks like this:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;

public class Plethora extends MovieClip {

        public function Plethora(): void {
        var m:uint=200;
        var n:uint=200;
        var boardArray:Array = [[0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]];
        for (var i:uint=0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (var j:uint=0; j <3; j++) {
                if (boardArray[i,j] == 1){
                    var thisBlock: Block = new Block();
                    thisBlock.stop();
                    thisBlock.x = m;
                    thisBlock.y = n;
                    addChild(thisBlock);
                }
                m = m -50;
            }
            n = n - 50;
        }
    }
}
  }
```

When I test-run it, I get the following output:

```
          verify Plethora$iinit()
                        stack:
                        scope: [global Object$ flash.events::EventDispatcher$  flash.display::DisplayObject$ flash.display::InteractiveObject$ flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$ flash.display::Sprite$ flash.display::MovieClip$ Plethora$] 
                         locals: Plethora * * * * * * 
  0:getlocal0
                        stack: Plethora
                        scope: [global Object$ flash.events::EventDispatcher$ flash.display::DisplayObject$ flash.display::InteractiveObject$ flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$ flash.display::Sprite$ flash.display::MovieClip$ Plethora$] 
                         locals: Plethora * * * * * * 
  1:pushscope
                        stack:
                        scope: [global Object$ flash.events::EventDispatcher$ flash.display::DisplayObject$ flash.display::InteractiveObject$ flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$ flash.display::Sprite$ flash.display::MovieClip$ Plethora$] Plethora 

...

                         locals: Plethora? uint uint Array? uint uint Block 
  136:findpropstrict addChild
                        stack: Array? Plethora
                        scope: [global Object$ flash.events::EventDispatcher$ flash.display::DisplayObject$ flash.display::InteractiveObject$ flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$
```

I haven't the slightest idea what any of that could even begin to mean. I would appreciate some hints about how to start debugging this.

Answer (score 3):

There may be something weird going on inside your Block MovieClip. Do you have any code in there? Also your 2D array syntax is incorrect:

```
boardArray[i, j]
```

Should be:

```
boardArray[i][j]
```

After making that change I copied your code on to wonderful and ran it - it seems to work fine. [Have a look.](http://wonderfl.net/c/u7Bh)

Comment: +1. You're right about the syntax being the culprit here. If you want to take a look at some of the gory details behind this error, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003286/error-1030-stack-depth-is-unbalanced/